# ejb not merging to db

Tags: jpa, sql-update, ejb

I have a structure with a jpa,ejb,backingbean,jsp.  I am able to query the db and return results to the page but when I try to merge (update) ejb it does not work.  No errors but it does not update the value.  For testing I just hard coded the values.  If you can tell me what I am doing work I would really appreciate it:

jpa:

```
package com.ray.adtf.jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the GRIDWEIGHT database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="Gridweight.findAll", query="SELECT g FROM Gridweight g"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Gridweight.findByGridid", query = "SELECT g FROM Gridweight g WHERE g.gridid = :gridid")
        })
public class Gridweight implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long gridid;

    private String checking;

    private String drawing;

    private String modeling;

    @Column(name="\"RELEASE\"")
    private String release;

    private String structural;

    private String thermal;

    public Gridweight() {
    }

    public long getGridid() {
        return this.gridid;
    }

    public void setGridid(long gridid) {
        this.gridid = gridid;
    }

    public String getChecking() {
        return this.checking;
    }

    public void setChecking(String checking) {
        this.checking = checking;
    }

    public String getDrawing() {
        return this.drawing;
    }

    public void setDrawing(String drawing) {
        this.drawing = drawing;
    }

    public String getModeling() {
        return this.modeling;
    }

    public void setModeling(String modeling) {
        this.modeling = modeling;
    }

    public String getRelease() {
        return this.release;
    }

    public void setRelease(String release) {
        this.release = release;
    }

    public String getStructural() {
        return this.structural;
    }

    public void setStructural(String structural) {
        this.structural = structural;
    }

    public String getThermal() {
        return this.thermal;
    }

    public void setThermal(String thermal) {
        this.thermal = thermal;
    }

}
```

ejb:

```
package com.ray.adtf.ejb;

import com.ray.adtf.jpa.Gridweight;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;

@Stateless
public class GridWeightBean  {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void updWeight(Gridweight gridweight) {
              em.merge(gridweight);
           }  

    public Gridweight getGridweight(Integer vgridid) {
        return em.createQuery("FROM Gridweight where gridid = "+ vgridid, Gridweight.class).getSingleResult();

    }

}
```

Backing bean:

```
package com.ray.adtf.web;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import com.ray.adtf.ejb.*;
import com.ray.adtf.jpa.Gridweight;

@ManagedBean
public class gridWeight {

    @EJB
    private GridWeightBean ejb;

    public Gridweight getGridWeight( int vgridid) {

        Gridweight weight1 = ejb.getGridweight(vgridid);
        return weight1; 
    }

    public String updWeight() {
        Gridweight gw = ejb.getGridweight(2);
        gw.setGridid(2);
        gw.setDrawing("99");
        ejb.updWeight(gw);
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Thank you !!!

Comment: not sure it was not showing the jsp code but it is:<h:commandButton value="Update Grid"
                      id="cmdUpd" 
                      action="#{gridWeight.updWeight()}"/>

Comment: Could you also provide backingbean code?

Comment: not sure why the backing bean did not post......any help would be great thank you

Answer (score 0):

Where is your instance coming from? How do you handle transactions in PU/code? There are more things to check:

How did you get Gridweight? *Merge* simply does nothing in some entity states:

- if the entity is already in the persistence context (session), no action is taken, except for cascades
- if the entity is detached, a copy (object) is returned, which is attached (managed)
- if the entity is transient (new instance), it is saved and a persistent (and managed) copy is returned
- if the entity is detached, but an object with the same identifier exist in the current entity manager, then the state of the detached object is copied into the current persistent entity, and it (the current) is returned

You also have to handle your transactions properly. Changes are not wisible in the database until you commit transaction which contains *merge* call.

*Merge* cost more machine resources than *persist* so if you are just storing new instance it's better to use *persist*.

Comment: Hi could you look at the code again?  For some reason the backing bean code was removed when I posted the question... it should be there now and this will answer most of the issues you posted above.  thank you